# i am getting error Google disallowed useragent in iphone but the same code is working on android but not in iphone using phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

THis is the code i used to auth with google, which is perfectly working on android but not working in iphon, i am getting this error
**ERROR 403 Google disallowed useragent**

```
var openAuthWindow = function(){
    var urlAuth = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?"
        + "scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&"
        + "redirect_uri=http://localhost&"
        + "response_type=code&"
        + "client_id=" + clientId;


    // Open InAppBrowser to get authorization code
    authWindow = window.open(urlAuth, '_blank', 'location=no');
    authWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', parseRedirectUrl);
```